# Run Git GUI and Tortoise GUI in parallel

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, git-gui

GIT on Windows 7:

Is it possible to run GitGUI and Tortoise GIT in parallel? In a current project, some steps require me to use GitGUI, while I am used to Tortoise GIT.

Can I run them both in parallel? Especially on the same project.

If so, when I install Git GUI, it allows me to install a Explorer integration as well. Tortoise has it is own Explorer integration, so I wonder if this might cause trouble. Or can I use both Explorer integrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I run them both in parallel?

Yes: both will display the same state both the repository monitored.
Same indexed files will be listed, same commits will be listed.

You *could* have an issue if you were to attempt a commit *simultaneously* from *both* tools, but I don't think anyone would want to do that.

> can I use both Explorer integration?

You should be able to use both, as each one will refer to its own Git program.